# "return of graph.facebook api image as byte[]" VS "Bitmap compressed as byte[]"

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, bitmapfactory

When I get image from graph.facebook API, it can be easyly converted into Bitmap with this structure:

`Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(src , 0, src .length);`

But after I get picture from gallery and compress it to send my server DB as byte[], there is problem while decoding it with same function.

```
Bitmap bitmap = getImagefromGallery();
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bitmap.getByteCount());
bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);
byte[] result = buffer.array();
```

And facebook's image sizes is much more smaller then mines, even though dimensions are the same.

Why is this happening? How can I compress images from Bitmap to byte[] as facebook's format?